# Can't Connect with memcache server

Tags: php, web-services

I've installed memcache perfectly and I have created a new instance but i don't understand if I'm connecting to the right port or not.It always returns "Could not connect"

Here is my code:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->connect('localhost',11211) or die ("Could not connect");

$version = $memcache->getVersion();
echo "Server's version: ".$version."<br/>\n";

$tmp_object = new stdClass;
$tmp_object->str_attr = 'test';
$tmp_object->int_attr = 123;

$memcache->set('key', $tmp_object, false, 10) or die ("Failed to save data at the server");
echo "Store data in the cache (data will expire in 10 seconds)<br/>\n";

$get_result = $memcache->get('key');
echo "Data from the cache:<br/>\n";
```

Comment: can you connect with telnet to memcache?

Comment: I am checking it on Linux server. In my server, i have already installed Memcache.